# systemctl status with failed about Failed to parse usec_t value

Tags: systemd, rhel, services, systemctl

I get very strange failed errors from systemctl status as - `Failed to parse usec_t value`

example

```
systemctl status loij12.service

.
.
.
.

Jan 05 16:44:59 master_linux.loij12.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/ght_hj.service:17] Failed to parse usec_t value, ignoring: 30s # time to sleep before restarting the service
Jan 05 16:44:59 master_linux.loij12.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/ght_hj.service:17] Failed to parse usec_t value, ignoring: 30s # time to sleep before restarting the service
```

but cant understand this failed about - `Failed to parse usec_t value`

because I cant also find the value as `usec_t` in the service itself

any idea how to continue from this stage and what this failed is meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a syntax error in `ght_hj.service` (assuming that the failure of the latter will cause the former to fail too) on line 17 which causes a dependency to fail for `loij12.service`.

Check out [RestartSec=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=).  If it looks like this:

```
RestartSec=30s # time to sleep before restarting the service
```

You'll have an error. You can't put comments to the right of the content.   Replace it with:

```
# time to sleep before restarting the service
RestartSec=30s
```

See [systemd.syntax(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.syntax.html) which says

> Empty lines and lines starting with "#" or ";" are ignored, which may be used for commenting.

If `#` is not at the start of the line, then it doesn't mean anything and could be considered part of the data on the line.